# How is learning rate calculated in sklearn Lasso regression?

Tags: linear-regression, regularization, learning-rate, ridge-regression, lasso

I was applying different regression models to Kaggle Housing dataset for advanced regression. I am planning to test out [lasso](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html), [ridge](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) and [elastic net](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html). However, none of these models have learning rate as their parameter.

How is the learning rate calculated for these model? Is it dependent on the dataset being trained? I know these models are regularized linear regression and must use learning rate to update their model weights. Or is their a different way to update the model?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469237/linear-regression-and-gradient-descent-in-scikit-learn-pandas/34470001#34470001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sklearn you can have two approaches for linear regression:

1) `LinearRegression` object uses Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) solver from scipy, as Learning rate (LR) is one of two classifiers which have **closed form solution**. This is achieve by just inverting and multiplicating some matrices.

2) `SGDRegressor` which is an implementation of **stochastic gradient descent**, very generic one where you can choose your penalty terms. To obtain linear regression you choose loss to be `L2` and penalty also to `none` (linear regression) or `L2` (Ridge regression)

There is no "typical gradient descent" because it is **rarely used** in practise. If you can decompose your loss function into additive terms, then stochastic approach is known to behave better (thus SGD) and if you can spare enough memory - OLS method is faster and easier (thus first solution).

This answer is mostly extracted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469237/linear-regression-and-gradient-descent-in-scikit-learn-pandas/34470001#34470001 
The OP @Netro is and the answer is from @lejlot